# Trouble implementing unsigned component to conditions of ALU in VHDL

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl, unsigned, alu

I have to create an ALU that has conditions for add, add unsigned, sub, sub unsigned, and, or, xor, nor, slt, and slt unsigned. I am having difficulty implementing the design to include the unsigned conditions. I have noted in the code where the errors are occurring. Also, every other aspect of the ALU works correct, it is ONLY the unsigned portion I need help with. I was researching about unsigned and std_logic but I was unable to find the problems similar to mine.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use ieee.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity ALU is
Port (A, B     : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
      ALUCntl  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
      Carryin  : in  STD_LOGIC;
      ALUOut   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
      Zero     : out STD_LOGIC;
      Carryout : out STD_LOGIC;
      Overflow : out STD_LOGIC);
end ALU; 


architecture Behavioral of ALU is
signal ALU_Result, slt, sltu : std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
signal add_result,sub_result,a32,b32: std_logic_vector(32 downto 0);
-- create separate a and b for unsigned 
signal add_u,sub_u,a32u,b32u: unsigned(32 downto 0);
signal c32: std_logic_vector(32 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
signal add_ov,sub_ov:std_logic;

begin
with ALUCntl select
ALU_Result <=add_result(31 downto 0) when "0010", -- add
            sub_result(31 downto 0) when "0110", -- sub
            slt     when "0111", -- set less than
            std_logic_vector(add_u(31 downto 0)) when "0100", -- add unsigned 
            std_logic_vector(sub_u(31 downto 0)) when "0101", -- sub unsigned
            sltu    when "1000", -- set less than unsigned
            A AND B when "0000",
            A OR  B when "0001",
            A XOR B when "0011",
            A NOR B when "1100",
            A when others;---condition for all other alu control signals
ALUOut  <= ALU_Result; 
----Set less than-----------------------------------
process(a32,b32)
begin
if (a32 < b32) then 
    slt <= x"00000001";
else
    slt <= x"00000000";
end if;
end process;
process(a32u,b32u)
begin
if (a32u < b32u) then 
    sltu <= x"00000001";
else
    sltu <= x"00000000";
end if;
end process;
----Addition Operation and carry out generation-----    
a32   <='0'& A;
b32   <='0'& B;
c32(0)<=Carryin;
add_result<=std_logic_vector(signed(a32) + signed(b32) + signed(c32));
sub_result<=std_logic_vector(signed(a32) - signed(b32));

a32u   <=unsigned('0'& A);
b32u   <=unsigned('0'& B);
add_u<=a32u + b32u + unsigned(c32);
sub_u<=a32u - b32u;

---Zero flag-----------------------------   
Zero <= '1' when ALU_Result =x"00000000" else '0';

---Overflow flag---------------------------------------
add_ov<= (A(31)and B(31)       and (not alu_result(31))) or ((not A(31))and (not B(31)) and alu_result(31));
sub_ov<= (A(31)and (not B(31)) and (not alu_result(31))) or ((not A(31))and B(31)       and alu_result(31)); 
with ALUCntl select
  Overflow<= add_ov when "0010" | "0100",
             sub_ov when "0110" | "0101",
             'Z' when others;

---Carryout-------------------------------------------------
With ALUCntl select 
Carryout<= add_result(32) when "0010",
            sub_result(32) when "0110",
            add_u(32)      when "0100",
            sub_u(32)      when "0101",
            'Z' when others;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Provide the complete actual error messages (with the line numbers). Types unsigned and std_logic_vector are closely related and can use [type conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s79XI.jpg). There are no arithmetic operators that mix and match the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone through it thoroughly. The main issue is type conversions, so I've commented where I've added them. I've also tweaked some of the code to make it more readable by adding constants for the command names which is generally good practice, and a case statement for command selection. And `std_logic_unsigned` is a deprecated non standard library.

I've updated it in keeping with your updates to your original question regarding the processing of unsigned logic. I've also added a couple more constants and three subtypes in keeping with the design principle of only having one version of the truth.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
--use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;  -- Not advisable to use this non standard library.
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ALU is
    generic
    (
        ALU_BITS: natural := 32  -- Added a generic parameter to specify the number of bits in the ALU.
    );
    port
    (
        A, B     : in  std_logic_vector (ALU_BITS - 1 downto 0);
        ALUCntl  : in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        Carryin  : in  std_logic;
        ALUOut   : out std_logic_vector (ALU_BITS - 1 downto 0);
        Zero     : out std_logic;
        Carryout : out std_logic;
        Overflow : out std_logic
    );
end ALU;

architecture Behavioral of ALU is

    -- Added some constants and subtypes to make the code more readable and maintainable.

    constant ALU_MSB: natural := ALU_BITS - 1;

    subtype TALURegister is std_logic_vector(ALU_MSB downto 0);
    subtype TALURegisterX is std_logic_vector(ALU_BITS downto 0);
    subtype TALURegisterXU is unsigned(ALU_BITS downto 0);

    constant ALU_REGISTER_ZERO: TALURegister := (others => '0');
    constant ALU_REGISTER_ONE : TALURegister := (ALU_MSB downto 1 => '0') & '1';

    constant CMD_ADD   : std_logic_vector := "0010";
    constant CMD_SUB   : std_logic_vector := "0110";
    constant CMD_SLT   : std_logic_vector := "0111";
    constant CMD_SLT_U : std_logic_vector := "1000";
    constant CMD_ADD_U : std_logic_vector := "0100";
    constant CMD_SUB_U : std_logic_vector := "0101";
    constant CMD_AND   : std_logic_vector := "0000";
    constant CMD_OR    : std_logic_vector := "0001";
    constant CMD_XOR   : std_logic_vector := "0011";
    constant CMD_NOR   : std_logic_vector := "1100";

    signal ALU_Result, slt, sltu : TALURegister;
    signal add_result, sub_result, a32, b32: TALURegisterX;

    -- create separate a and b for unsigned
    signal add_u, sub_u, a32u, b32u: TALURegisterXU;
    signal c32: TALURegisterX := (others => '0');
    signal add_ov, sub_ov: std_logic;

    begin
        -- Alternative command selection using a case statement.
        process(ALUCntl, add_result, sub_result, slt, sltu, add_u, sub_u, A, B)
        begin
            case ALUCntl is
                when CMD_ADD    =>  ALU_Result <= add_result(ALU_MSB downto 0);
                when CMD_SUB    =>  ALU_Result <= sub_result(ALU_MSB downto 0);
                when CMD_SLT    =>  ALU_Result <= slt;
                when CMD_SLT_U  =>  ALU_Result <= sltu;
                when CMD_ADD_U  =>  ALU_Result <= TALURegister(add_u(ALU_MSB downto 0));  -- Added type conversion.
                when CMD_SUB_U  =>  ALU_Result <= TALURegister(sub_u(ALU_MSB downto 0));  -- Added type conversion.
                when CMD_AND    =>  ALU_Result <= A and B;
                when CMD_OR     =>  ALU_Result <= A or B;
                when CMD_XOR    =>  ALU_Result <= A xor B;
                when CMD_NOR    =>  ALU_Result <= A nor B;
                when others     =>  ALU_Result <= A;
            end case;
        end process;

        -- with ALUCntl select
            -- ALU_Result <=
                -- add_result(ALU_MSB downto 0) when CMD_ADD, -- add
                -- sub_result(ALU_MSB downto 0) when CMD_SUB, -- sub
                -- slt     when CMD_SLT, -- set less than

                -- - Getting an error that indexed name is not STD_LOGIC_VECTOR --
                -- TALURegister(add_u(ALU_MSB downto 0)) when CMD_ADD_U, -- add unsigned  -- Added type conversion.
                -- TALURegister(sub_u(ALU_MSB downto 0)) when CMD_SUB_U, -- sub unsigned  -- Added type conversion.
                ---------------------------------------------------------

                -- sltu    when CMD_SLT_U, -- set less than unsigned
                -- A AND B when CMD_AND,
                -- A OR  B when CMD_OR,
                -- A XOR B when CMD_XOR,
                -- A NOR B when CMD_NOR,
                -- A when others;---condition for all other alu control signals

        ALUOut  <= ALU_Result;

        ----Set less than-----------------------------------
        process(a32, b32)
        begin
            if (a32 < b32) then
                slt <= ALU_REGISTER_ONE;
            else
                slt <= ALU_REGISTER_ZERO;
            end if;
        end process;

        ----Set less than unsigned--------------------------
        process(a32u, b32u)
        begin
        if (a32u < b32u) then
            sltu <= ALU_REGISTER_ONE;
        else
            sltu <= ALU_REGISTER_ZERO;
        end if;
        end process;

        ----Addition Operation and carry out generation-----
        a32     <= '0' & A;
        b32     <= '0' & B;
        c32(0)  <= Carryin;
        add_result <= TALURegisterX(signed(a32) + signed(b32) + signed(c32));  -- Added type conversion.
        sub_result <= TALURegisterX(signed(a32) - signed(b32));                -- Added type conversion.

        -- Getting "'0' definitions found" errors here --
        a32u  <= TALURegisterXU('0' & A);            -- Added type conversion.
        b32u  <= TALURegisterXU('0' & B);            -- Added type conversion.
        add_u <= a32u + b32u + TALURegisterXU(c32);  -- Added type conversion.
        sub_u <= a32u - b32u;

        -------------------------------------------------
        ---Zero flag-----------------------------
        Zero <= '1' when ALU_Result = ALU_REGISTER_ZERO else '0';

        ---Overflow flag---------------------------------------
        add_ov <= (A(ALU_MSB) and B(ALU_MSB)       and (not alu_result(ALU_MSB))) or ((not A(ALU_MSB)) and (not B(ALU_MSB)) and alu_result(ALU_MSB));
        sub_ov <= (A(ALU_MSB) and (not B(ALU_MSB)) and (not alu_result(ALU_MSB))) or ((not A(ALU_MSB)) and B(ALU_MSB)       and alu_result(ALU_MSB));
        with ALUCntl select
            Overflow <=
                add_ov when CMD_ADD | CMD_ADD_U,
                sub_ov when CMD_SUB | CMD_SUB_U,
                'Z' when others;

        ---Carryout-------------------------------------------------
        with ALUCntl select
            Carryout <=
                add_result(ALU_BITS) when CMD_ADD,
                sub_result(ALU_BITS) when CMD_SUB,
                add_u(ALU_BITS)      when CMD_ADD_U,
                sub_u(ALU_BITS)      when CMD_SUB_U,
                'Z' when others;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Thank you. The principal design is working in the simulation now. I have edited the above code with the changes I made (Note: I couldn't completely change the design to match yours as the formatting is strict)

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. I've updated it in keeping with your updates to your original question regarding the processing of unsigned logic. I've also added a couple more constants and three subtypes in keeping with the design principle of only having one version of the truth. Were you able to use constants? I'd be surprised the formatting was so strict that you are not allowed to use constants.

Answer (score 1):

So without looking at the details, I can tell you why you're having compilation issues for the first error. First, lets look at your signals. They are all declared as the unsigned type.

```vhdl
signal add_u,sub_u,a32u,b32u: unsigned(32 downto 0);
```

However, your `ALUOut` output port is of the `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` type. You will have issues because `signed` is not the same as `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`. Luckily for you, it's very easy to cast to and from these types. I actually keep [this nandland conversion cheatsheet](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tips/tip-convert-numeric-std-logic-vector-to-integer.html) handy at all times.

Try the following. It should cast your signed type to an STD_LOGIC_VECTOR.

```vhdl
ALU_Result <=add_result(31 downto 0) when "0010", -- add
            sub_result(31 downto 0) when "0110", -- sub
            slt     when "0111", -- set less than

            ----- Getting an error that indexed name is not STD_LOGIC_VECTOR --
            STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(add_u(31 downto 0)) when "0100", -- add unsigned 
            STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(sub_u(31 downto 0)) when "0101", -- sub unsigned
```

---

So as a crash course review I'll describe how I think about std_logic_vector, signed, and unsigned. Yet again, [nandland has a good review of these types](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-signed-unsigned.html). Here is how I imagine it:

1. `std_logic_vector` does not know whether the vector of STD_LOGIC is supposed to be signed or unsigned representation. Therefore, any addition, subtraction, and multiplication operations won't work.
2. `signed` is interpreting a vector of std_logic as using two's compliments form. This allows for the addition, subtraction, and multiplication of the signed types together
3. `unsigned` is similar to signed, but assumes that the integers are unsigned representation.

If you are trying to not used `signed` or `unsigned` for an assignment, then you will need to implement the logic. However, you can let the signed and unsigned types implement the logic for you.

So let's add two types of `std_logic_vector`. As you see below, I cast the A and B vectors to signed/unsigned, then cast back to `std_logic_vector`.

```vhdl
signal A, B: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal result: std_logic_vector(31 + 1 downto 0);
-- Lets add them together as though they were unsigned
-- We pad a 0 to the end of the value to extend its length
result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned('0' & A) + unsigned(B));
-- Lets add them together as though they were signed
-- We copy the last bit of A for signed values
result <= std_logic_vector(signed((A(31) & & A) + signed(B));
```

I hope this helps!